# Como restaurar as configurações de fábrica do Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Minha IDE do Android Studio está dando muitos problemas para compilar meu projeto android... Como faço para dar um "reset" nela?

Answer (score 1):

O `Android Studio` salva suas configurações em uma pasta chamada `.AndroidStudio` que, geralmente, fica em `C:\Users\seuusuario`.

Para resetar as configurações, simplesmente delete essa pasta e abra novamente o seu `Android Studio`.

Lembrando que, esses problemas podem não ser especificadamente do Android Studio, podendo ser, por exemplo, de como seu `build.gradle` esta configurado, as configurações da VM do seu `Android Studio` ou simplesmente configurações de sua máquina (como processamento e memória RAM)