# Android Studio não salva as alterações do projeto

Tags: android, android-studio

Antes deste problema acontecer, eu compilava e recompilava os meus projetos sem ocorrer nenhum problema. Porém no momento, quando vou compilar o meu projeto, o IDE compila o estado original do projeto, ou seja, ele compila o código anterior à alteração feita por mim.

Comment: Oi Everton, tudo bem? Cara, é muito difícil responder sua pergunta apenas com as informações que você passou. O *Toolset* no meio do caminho é enorme. Só o que me vem a cabeça são coisas mais óbvias do tipo checar a opção de *build automático*, invalidar o cache e verificar se você não está com erros de compilação na versão atual do seu *app* (dê uma olhada nessa resposta do SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26206715/664577). Dê uma olhada nessas opções, se nenhuma delas resolver tente atualizar sua pergunta com mais informações.

Answer (score 0):

[como restaurar as configurações do Android Studio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51218/como-restaurar-as-configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-f%C3%A1brica-do-android-studio)

Se já o fez, mas não funcionou, atualize seu Android Studio.

A versão atual do `Android Studio` é a `1.1` que foi lançada a pouco tempo. Se você ainda não atualizou, siga o tutorial abaixo:

> Help > Check for Updates

Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre os releases na página [tools-android/recent](http://tools.android.com/recent)

Comment: a versão atual da IDE Android Studio é a 2.1 developer.android.com/sdk/index.html